# Background image is not showing in pdf file when using Dompdf laravel6

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-6, dompdf

Controller

```
use PDF;
class PdfController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
       return view('pdf/web',compact('data'))
    }
    public function generate(){
        $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf -> loadView('pdf/web',compact('data'));
        return $pdf->stream();
    }
}
```

web.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>100001</title>
<style type="text/css">
   
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin-top:0.5cm;
        margin-bottom:0;
        margin-left:0;
        margin-right:0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .firstdiv{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        width: 1200px;
        height: 900px;
        background-image: url("/img/bgimg.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="firstdiv">
          #CONTENTS
          #CONTENTS
          #CONTENTS
          #CONTENTS
    </div>
```

There are two types of problem I am facing

1. When I open the webpage everything works fine. When it comes to the dompdf, the background image is not showing in the pdf file. For more clearance: I am trying to view a webpage and create pdf from the same. When I open the web page using the index function of the controller. everything I designed is working fine. But the pdf file is opening with contents only, it is not showing the background image.
2. My design have width of 1000px and 630px height. So I want PDF in landscape mode. But pdf is coming in portrait mode. rest of the section showing blank space in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using javascript libraries for this. because they export your page after rendering everything. I have used jspdf+html2canvas for exporting certification in a project and it worked fine. also i recently found puppeteer which i think is awesome.

jspdf+html2canvas:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/boLxkgj8/14/
```

puppeteer:

```
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
```

Comment: The problem is I want to save pdf file to server, Can I do that if I use javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with puppeteer. see the document here:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.3.1/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions